# What are the raw materials for water filter housing production?

Tags: materials, chemical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering

I want produce water filter housing (like below images)
who can tell me what are need raw material for these?
Best Regards

[image: water filter housing]

[image: water filter housing]

Comment: Your question isn't clear, which is why I have closed it.  Are you looking for the types of plastics in order to be used with a mold to make those objects?  Or are you looking for sources for those canisters?  Or ... ?